# Google Drive API only returning a single file

Tags: node.js, google-api

I have a nodejs app where I would like to get a list of the files in a google drive with the google drive api.  I'm using a service account key for the auth method.  The problem I'm having is that when I run it, I only get a list of a single file back (the 'getting started' file).  I have 4 other files added in there but they aren't coming through.  When I use the sandbox method in the google api console I get all of the files.  Below is my code.  Any idea on why the other files aren't coming through.  I've tried adding more scopes but that didn't seem to help.

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var key = require('./jwt-file.json');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'], null);
var drive = google.drive('v3');
jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return; 
    }

    drive.files.list({auth: jwtClient}, function(err, response){
        console.log(response)
    })
})
```